# Propel equivalent of "exists"

Tags: php, sql, propel

I am new to Propel and have been reading the documentation.  But, I have not found a clear equivalent to the EXISTS and NOT EXISTS constructs from SQL.  Linq in .NET, for instance, has Any().  Is there an equivalent to the following in "idiomatic" Propel?

```
SELECT a.column1, a column2, a.etc
FROM   TableA a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   TableB b
                   WHERE  b.someIdColumn = a.someIdColumn
                   AND    b.aNullableDateColumn IS NULL)
```

Comment: Did you mean "proper"? (title)

Comment: @Trufa No, Propel, as in the ORM: http://www.propelorm.org/

Comment: sorry for my complete ignorance!! no idea what you are talking about, Thats why I didn't edit! hehe that would have been embarrassing :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some more digging, I believe I have an answer to my question, or at least as good an answer as is currently available.

What comes after EXISTS or NOT EXISTS is a subquery.  While that fact seems obvious, it did not originally occur to me to focus my search for help on subqueries.  I found a [few](http://www.mail-archive.com/symfony-users@googlegroups.com/msg01652.html) [resources](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/75) on the topic.  Essentially, the options are to rewrite the query using JOINs (as is the heart of the answer by @Kaltas) or to use `Criteria::CUSTOM`.  I decided I would likely prefer the second option, since it allows me to keep the subquery, potentially helping my database performance.

I did a lot of reading, then, about `Criteria::CUSTOM`, but the only reading that really helped me was reading the Propel 1.5 source.  It's very simple, really.  Just put the subquery, verbatim (using the database's table and column names, *not* Propel's object names) along with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS in the `where` call, like:

```
TableAQuery::create()
    ->where('NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB WHERE TableA.someIdColumn = TableB.someIdColumn AND TableB.aNullableDateColumn IS NULL)')
    ->find();
```

It's that simple.  Internally, the `where` method goes through a few possibilities for interpreting the clause, and finding no matches, it treats the clause as being of `Criteria::CUSTOM` and inserts it into the SQL query as-is.  So, I could not use table aliases, for example.

If I ever have time, maybe I'll work on a more "ORM-ish" way to do this and submit a patch.  Someone will probably beat me to it, though.

Answer (score 1):

As in propel 1.6 u now can use `Criteria::IN` and `Criteria::NOT_IN`

Example : Select all users that are not in an UserGroup

```
$users = UserQuery::create()->filterById(UserPerUserGroupQuery::create()->select('user_id')->find(), CRITERIA::NOT_IN)
                             ->orderByUserName()
                             ->find();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT
  a.column1,
  a.column2,
  a.etc
FROM
  TableA a
WHERE
  (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    TableB b
  WHERE
    b.someIdColumn = a.someIdColumn
      AND
    b.aNullableDateColumn IS NULL
  ) > 0
```

which is easily doable in Propel.

Or even cleaner and easier to accomplish in Propel:

```
SELECT
  a.column1,
  a.column2,
  a.etc
FROM
  TableA a
    LEFT JOIN
  TableB b ON (b.someIdColumn = a.someIdColumn)
WHERE
  b.aNullableDateColumn IS NULL
    AND
  b.primaryKeyColumn IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think it would be workable, but I found something I like a little better for the situation in which I am actually using this code.

Comment: I see your response - if using hand-written SQL is OK for you in this case it's an easiest and fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

Propel 2 can do:

```php
TableAQuery::create()
  ->useTableBNotExistsQuery()
  ->filterByNullableDateColumn(null)
  ->endUse()
  ->find();
```

or

```php
$nestedB = TableBQuery::create()
  ->filterByNullableDateColumn(null)
  ->where('TableB.someIdColumn = TableA.someIdColumn');
TableAQuery::create()->whereExists(nestedB)->find();
```